# Sending image file via AJAX. request.FILES is empty?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, http, post

I am trying to send image data using Ajax. But `request.FILES` that I get at the backend is empty. I have added `multipart/form-data` to my form and the method is `POST`.

here is my AJAX call:

```
 $(document).on('submit', '#profile_edit_form', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();


  $.ajax({
      url     : "/users/update_profile_info/",
      type    : 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data    : $(this).serialize(),
      success : function(data) {

        $('#profile_name_tag').html(data.username);
        $('#username_navbar').html(data.username);

        //SENDING THE IMAGE VIA AJAX HERE
        var img_data = $('#id_image').get(0).files;
        formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("img_data", img_data);

        $.ajax({
            url         : "/users/update_profile_image/",
            type        : 'POST',
            enctype     : "multipart/form-data",
            data        : formdata,
            cache       : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
              console.log('success');
              //$('#profile_picture').html(data.)

            },
            error: function(data) {
              console.log('fail');
            }
        });

      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log('fail');
      }
  });


});
```

and here is my form:

```
   <form id="profile_edit_form" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <fieldset class="form-group">
       <legend class="border-bottom mb4"> Profile Info </legend>
             {{u_form|crispy}}
            {{p_form|crispy}}
     </fieldset>
     <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"> Update Info </button>
   </form>
```

As you can see  I am using cispy forms. the image field is inside the `p_form`

and here is my `django view`

```
@login_required
def update_profile_image(request):
    print(not request.FILES)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()

            context = {'None': 'none'}
            return JsonResponse(context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('None')
```

`print(not request.FILES)` returns True and the image is of course not uploaded.

I have checked so many similar questions. but in all of them the solution was adding `multipart/form-data` to the form which I have already done. 
So any ideas where the problem is?

thanks!

Comment: Remove the manual `enctype` setting as jQuery will do that for you. Then try just `var img_data = $('#id_image').get(0).files[0]` as `files` is a collection, and it's possible `append()` only wants a single file.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the suggestion. i did as you said but I still get an empty request.FILES

Comment: I can't see anything specifically wrong in your logic, so long as the first AJAX request is successful and the `#id_image` element exists and contains a file. Could you show us the Django code where you attempt to read the files. I'm not a Django expert, but I'm sure someone else will be able to check it for you

Comment: $(this).serialize() be careful of your scope when passing the data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan trying var `var img_data = $('#id_image').get(0).files[0]` actually worked. write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added the answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the code to

```
var img_data = $('#id_image').get(0).files[0];
formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("img_data", img_data);
//console.log(formdata.get("img_data"));

$.ajax({
    url         : "/users/update_profile_image/",
    type        : 'POST',
    //enctype     : "multipart/form-data",   //it is done inside jquery
    data        : formdata,
    cache       : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {
      console.log('success');
      //$('#profile_picture').html(data.)

    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('image-fail');
    }
});
```

and it finally worked!

Answer (score 2):

You're providing the entire `files` collection to `FormData.append()`, when it expects a single entity.

Try just accessing the single file from `files` and passing that instead:

```
var img_data = $('#id_image').get(0).files[0]; // note [0]
```

I would also suggest removing the `enctype` settings, as jQuery will do this for you automatically when you provide a `FormData` object to the request. Manually setting the value may overwrite the setting with an incorrect value.

Comment: thanks. using your suggestion and some other modifications it finally worked!