# Django sending image file through ajax but request.FILES is empty

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image via a post request using AJAX to the server (localhost). The image gets saved in the media folder. If I do `print(request.FILES['image']`, it prints the name of the image file. But if I do `print(request.FILES['image'].read()` it is empty. I've looked at a similar question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858520/sending-image-file-via-ajax-request-files-is-empty) and tried the approach, however, it didn't work for me.

Here is my index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
{% load static %}

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.25/webcam.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="submitimage" action="/upload/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="file" id='image' name="image">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id='uploadPic'/>
    </form>
</body>

<script>
  $('#submitimage').submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url     : '/upload/',
      type    : 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data    : $(this).serialize(),
      success : function(data) {
                console.log("calling ajax");
                var img_data = $('#image').get(0).files[0];
                var data= new FormData(this);
                // var img_data = $('#image').get(0).files[0];
                data.append("img_data",img_data);
                console.log(data);
                // console.log(data.get("img_data"));
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/upload/',
                    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                    data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                           "imgfile": data },
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Image uploaded");
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                    console.log("Couldn't upload the image");
                    }
                });
            return false;
      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log('fail');
      }
            });
          });
</script>
```

This is my views.py:

```
def uploadpic(request):
# print(not request.FILES)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    # print(request.FILES['image'])
    form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print("image saved")
        print("in the upload pic")
        print(request.FILES['image'])
        print(request.FILES['image'].read())
        return HttpResponse('image upload success')
return HttpResponseForbidden('allowed only via POST')
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class MyImageModel(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'image/')
data=models.TextField()
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import MyImageModel
from django import forms
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyImageModel
        fields = ('image', )
```

urls.py:

```
from . import views as imageapiviews
path('upload/',imageapiviews.uploadpic, name='upload' ),
```

Comment: did you check what you have in file on disk ? Maybe it already read all data from request and when you use `.read()` then it reads from end of file. In other situations after reading all data from file you have to move to its beginning using `.seek(0)` before you read it again.

Comment: @furas Yes, I did. The file on the disk is an image file that I'm uploading using django form. I also tried using .seek(0) instead of .read() but still getting the same error. I've posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545751/opencv4-2-0-error-215assertion-failed-buf-empty-in-function-cvimdec ... have a look at it.

Comment: maybe read it from disk instead of using `.read()` - I don't know what `ImageUploadForm`  is doing but maybe it saves on disk and removes from memory and from `request.FILES`

Comment: As for me you send image two times `data    : $(this).serialize(),` and later the same with `data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", "imgfile": data },`. I don't have minimal working code to test if they really send image.