# OpenCV(4.2.0) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !buf.empty() in function 'cv::imdecode_'

Tags: python, django, opencv

I'm trying to upload an image using Django forms and post it to the server. But I'm getting the following error:

OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:730: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !buf.empty() in function 'cv::imdecode_'

Here is my views.py:

```
def uploadpic(request):
print(not request.FILES)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print("image saved")
        print("in the upload pic")
        print(request.FILES['image'])
        photo = request.FILES['image'].read()   #I also tried using seek(0) instead of read() 
        print(photo)
        npimg = np.fromstring(photo,np.uint8)
        print(npimg)
        img = cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
        knownImage_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    return HttpResponse('image upload success')
return HttpResponseForbidden('allowed only via POST')
```

Edit: the issue gets resolved after removal of the line form.save() , at least that's what worked for me.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: always put error as text, not image. it is easier to copy some element from text then rewrite it from image.

Comment: error meas you try to use empty data so you have again problem with getting image from client/browser. Like in previous question [Django sending image file through ajax but request.FILES is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507183/django-sending-image-file-through-ajax-but-request-files-is-empty)

Comment: @furas thanks for suggestions. The program works fine now. The problem was maybe what you mentioned–the image gets saved in the file system but it is deleted from the memory and request.files